# Remove "encoding" attribute from XML in Python

Tags: python, xml, encoding, elementtree, xml-declaration

I am using python to do some conditional changes to an XML document.  The incoming document has `<?xml version="1.0" ?>` at the top.

I'm using `xml.etree.ElementTree`.

How I'm parsing the changed XMl:

```
filter_update_body = ET.tostring(root, encoding="utf8", method="xml")
```

The output has this at the top:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>
```

The client wants the "encoding" tag removed but if I remove it then it either doesn't include the line at all or it puts in `encoding= 'us-ascii'`

Can this be done so the output matches: `<?xml version="1.0" ?>`?

(I don't know why it matters honestly but that's what I was told needed to happen)

Comment: You could just write the XML to string, modify the string, and then write it out.  `outxml = outxml.replace("encoding='utf8'", "", 1)`

Comment: I'm very new tp Python (we typically use JS and this is an edge case for us)
So I did this: `filter_update_body = ET.tostring(root, encoding="utf8", method="xml")
filter_update_body = filter_update_body.replace("encoding='utf8'", "", 1)`

and I got an error: "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Comment: That error isn't being caused by the string replacement. `replace` is a perfectly valid method of strings. Are you perhaps trying to write the file in binary mode?

Comment: Prefix both the strings in `replace` with `b` like this `replace(b"encoding='utf-8'", b"", 1)`

Comment: @Friedrich solution worked!  Thank you!  For my own knowledge, what does putting the `b` in there do?

Comment: `b`creates a bytes object. Which is what `bytes.replace()` asked for. It's all there, you just need to read it ;)

Comment: The alternative would be to call `ET.tostring(root, encoding="unicode")` and have a `str` returned. In that case, no `b`. String types in python can be tricky. The `type()` function is your friend if you want to know what you're dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72419151/796259) there is no way to make ElementTree omit the encoding attribute. However, as @James suggested in a comment, it can be stripped from the resulting output like this:

```py
filter_update_body = ET.tostring(root, encoding="utf8", method="xml")
filter_update_body = filter_update_body.replace(b"encoding='utf8'", b"", 1)
```

The `b` prefixes are required because `ET.tostring()` will return a `bytes` object  if `encoding != "unicode"`. In turn, we need to call `bytes.replace()`.

With `encoding = "unicode"` (note that this is the literal string "unicode"), it will return a regular `str`. In this case, the `b`s can be omitted. We use good old `str.replace()`.

It's worth noting that the choice between `bytes` and `str` also affects how the XML will eventually be written to a file. A `bytes` object should be written in binary mode, a `str` in text mode.